# CRUD with date (create and read)

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create a CRUD with 2 fields which are name and date.
In my Controller I suppose my function store is not good about date?

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('student.create');

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'date' => 'required'
        ]);
        Student::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('student.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');


    }
```

Here is my file create.blade.php

```
<form class="panel-body" action="{{route('student.store')}}" method="POST">
              @csrf
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="form-group-input-1">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1">
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="form-group-input-1">Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" >
              </fieldset>

              <a href="{{route('student.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Back</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>

            </form>
```

And index.blade.php

```
<table class="table">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{ route('student.create') }}">Create</a>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Firstname</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach($students as $student)
                <tr>
                   <td> {{$student->name}}</td>
                   <td> {{$student->date}} </td>
                   <td>
                     <form method="POST" action="{{ route('student.destroy', $student) }} ">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{route('student.edit',$student->id)}}">Edit</a>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
```

How to do so that the create from field "date" to be correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did, hope this helpfull:

In migrate my colume has type datetime

```
$table->dateTime('maintenance')->nullable();
```

Request rules:

```
'maintenance' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y'
```

Request message:

```
'maintenance.date_format' => ' Invalid date time ex: 01-07-2020'
```

Im my controller at create function

```
'maintenance'  =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($request->maintenance))
```

And input also:

```
<input type="text" name="maintenance" value="{{ date("d-m-Y", old('maintenance') ) }}" />
```

I need to read time with d-m-Y format. So add an mutator in model

```
protected $appends = ['maintenance_formated'];
//---
public function getMaintenanceFormatedAttribute()
{
    return date("d-m-Y", strtotime($this->maintenance));
}
```